# Org-ref not exporting citations properly to ODT format

Tags: bibtex, org-ref

I recently started using Org-ref to manage my references in Emacs. I have three devices that all share the same Emacs configuration. While org-ref exports successfully to Libreoffice/ODT on two of my machines, which both run Manjaro, the export function doesn't work on my main driver, which runs Arch.

When I tried to use org-ref's own export function to export an org file to Libreoffice ODT format (or LaTex, HTML, etc.), I got the error: citeproc-bt--to-csl-date: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil.

I debugged the export function, and got the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-to-number(nil)
  citeproc-bt--to-csl-date("Forthcoming" nil)
  citeproc-blt-entry-to-csl((("optannote" . "") ("optnote" . "") ("pages" . "331--352") ("optmonth" . "") ("optedition" . "") ("optaddress" . "") ("opttype" . "") ("optseries" . "") ("optnumber" . "") ("optvolume" . "") ("optkey" . "") ("year" . "Forthcoming") ("publisher" . "Östereichischen Akademie Wissenschaften") ("chapter" . "Veṅkaṭanātha on the superiority of the God Viṣṇu-N...") ("title" . "Changing Forms and the Becoming of a Deity in Indi...") ("editor" . "Marcus Schmücker") ("author" . "Marcus Schmücker") ("=type=" . "InBook") ("=key=" . "marcus_vn")))
  #f(compiled-function (key entry) #<bytecode 0x155b5e3107e1>)("marcus_vn" (("optannote" . "") ("optnote" . "") ("pages" . "331--352") ("optmonth" . "") ("optedition" . "") ("optaddress" . "") ("opttype" . "") ("optseries" . "") ("optnumber" . "") ("optvolume" . "") ("optkey" . "") ("year" . "Forthcoming") ("publisher" . "Östereichischen Akademie Wissenschaften") ("chapter" . "Veṅkaṭanātha on the superiority of the God Viṣṇu-N...") ("title" . "Changing Forms and the Becoming of a Deity in Indi...") ("editor" . "Marcus Schmücker") ("author" . "Marcus Schmücker") ("=type=" . "InBook") ("=key=" . "marcus_vn")))
  maphash(#f(compiled-function (key entry) #<bytecode 0x155b5e3107e1>) #<hash-table equal 361/487 0x155b5e1befbd>)
  citeproc-hash-itemgetter-from-any(("/home/michael/Dropbox/7_Bibliography/1_MASTER.bib"))
  org-ref-process-buffer(odt)
  org-ref-export-to(odt nil nil nil nil nil)
  org-ref-export-to-odt(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

From this, I guessed that the error occurs because citeproc is detecting formatting problems with the Bibtex entries in my database. I tried using a different and cleaner/smaller Bibtex database with an org file on the same Arch machine, and it successfully exported the document.

All machines are using the same Emacs configuration file and the same Bibtex/Org files, so I'm not clear why the package functions differently.

I would prefer that the export functions as it does on the Manjaro machines.

Comment: My only suggestion is to repeat the debugging experiment on one of your Manjaro machines and see what the arguments to `citeproc-bt--to-csl-date` are in that case (you can modify the function by adding `(debug)` as the first form to be evaluated inside it and then reevaluating the definition of the function with `C-M-x`): add any results to your question. John Kitchin (author of `org-ref`) is a frequent contributor here, so he might have better insights on both the problem, the solution and any debugging methods you can use to get there.

Comment: I would also check that you are using the same versions of citeproc on each machine. It doesn't make sense that you could be getting different results on different machines otherwise.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: As regarding the date processing error caused by "Forthcoming", this kind of information should go into the bib(la)tex field `pubstate` -- citeproc-el expects the `year` field to contain a numeric value.